# Reading selected value from struts2 jquery autocompleter using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, autocomplete

I have a jsp page and a struts2-jquery autocompleter in it. The autocompleter is loaded with values and whenever I select a value I want to retrieve that value to a JavaScript function.

My code is given below. But it is not working.

JavaScript code:

```
function loadAjax(){                        
  var empId=document.forms[0].employeename.value;
  alert("Value "+empId); 
}
```

Autocompleter code:

```
<sj:autocompleter name="employeename" id="employee" label="Employee ID" list="employeeMap" onchange="loadAjax();"/>
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<sj:autocompleter 
    id="employee" name="employeename" label="Employee ID" 
    list="employeeMap" onSelectTopics="loadAjax"/>
```

Add below mention code in you javascript section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.subscribe('loadAjax', function(event, data) 
{
     var empId = data.value;
     alert(empId);
});
</script>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<sx:head />
</head>


<body>
<h1>Struts 2 autocompleter + JSON example</h1>

<s:form action="resultAction" namespace="/" method="POST" >

<s:url id="databaseList" action="databaseJSON" />

<sx:autocompleter label="What's your favorite Database Server?" 
href="%{databaseList}" name="yourFavDatabase" />

<s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />

</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to get the selected value in JavaScript function. This code doesn't seems to have a valid JavaScript function. Anyway thanks for your try.

Answer (score 0):

onchange() event not working with JQuery Autocompleter. Try using a button and its onclick() event.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It would be helpful if you can figure out how to get the values with Autocompleter itself.

Answer (score 0):

[Use onSelectTopics](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag)

```
<sj:autocompleter name="employeename" id="employee" label="Employee ID" list="employeeMap" onSelectTopics="auto-select"/>

    <script>
    $(function(){
    $.subscribe("auto-select",function(event){
       console.log(event.originalEvent.event);
       console.log(event.originalEvent.ui);
       console.log(event.originalEvent.ui.item.desc);
       console.log(event.originalEvent.ui.item.value);
    });
});
</script>
```

Above code is untested and written using reference from [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

```
 $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
        $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );
```